# Add JSON data to a dropdown menu in every cell of the table (Tabulator.js)

Tags: javascript, json, drop-down-menu, tabulator

I'm kinda new to tabulator.js but so far, it's great but I have an issue.
I have a JSON file containing some clients.
Here is the data :

```js
{
  "clients": [
    {
      "city": "Brussels",
      "email": "benoit@gmail.com",
      "firstName": "Benoit",
      "idClient": 1,
      "lastName": "Dupont",
      "mailBox": "6",
      "phoneNumber": "0465237956",
      "postCode": "1200",
      "street": "Clos Chapelle-aux-Champs",
      "streetNumber": "43"
    }
  ]
}
```

For the moment, there's only one client but they will be more added to this json data in the future.
So I would like to add a dropdown menu in each row of the "Client" column like in the screenshot below.
https://ibb.co/8zH8S26

(link to my screenshot)

I've tried to follow the documentation of Tabulator.js on the matter but I can't seem to implement it well in my code with the JSON data

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#test", {
    data: response.users,
    index: "idUser",
    layout: "fitColumns",
    responsiveLayout: "hide",
    tooltips: true,
    addRowPos: "top",
    pagination: "local",
    paginationSize: 7,
    movableColumns: true,
    resizableRows: true,
    columns: [
        {title: "Registration Date", field: "registrationDate", formatter: dateFormatter},
        {title: "Worker", field: "worker", formatter: "tickCross", editor: true},
        {title: "First Name", field: "firstName"},
        {title: "Last Name", field: "lastName"},
        {title: "Username", field: "username"},
        {title: "Email", field: "email"},
        {title: "City", field: "city"},
        {
            title: "Client", editor: "select", editorParams: {
                values: {
                    // TODO INSERT THE VALUES OF THE JSON DATA HERE
                }
            }
        },
        {
            title: "", formatter: buttonTest, cellClick: function (e, cell) {
                const data = {
                    user: cell.getRow().getData().idUser,
                    worker: cell.getRow().getData().worker
                };

                updateData("users/" + data.user.idUser, data, token, function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }, function (response) {
                    console.log(response.error);
                })
            }
        }
    ],
});
```

https://ibb.co/TqqMqK1

(link to picture of the code)

Once the option from the dropdown is selected, i'd like to remember the id of the client that was selected.

I've tried almost every thing and nothing is working. Can you please help me?
Please don't hesitate illustrate your solution (I'm a visual learner).

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar using the following code:-

```
let clientSel={}
window.JQuery.ready(function(){
    // first create a json client list  
    let jsonStr = "[{'rid':'A01','desc':'client 1'}, {'ri'B01','desc':'client 2'}]"  
    let retJSON = JSON.parse(jsonStr)
    // create the cleinSel object from the json
    $(retJSON).each(index => {
        var key = retJSON[index].rid;
        var val = retJSON[index].desc 
        clientSel[key]=val;
    });
});


columns = [
    {title:"Client", field:"client",editor:"select", editorParams:function(cell){
        //create a options list of all values from another column in the table
        var rows = clientSel;
        return {values:rows};}, formatter:"lookup", formatterParams:function(){
            return clientSel},
    }
]
```

Hope this helps.